# Switch off `ivy-use-virtual-buffers` in spacemacs

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I would like to disable `ivy-use-virtual-buffers` in spacemacs.

However, adding `(setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers nil)` in either `user-init` or `user-config` doesn't work. Oh no!

I believe the source of the problem is this line in the spacemacs package initialisation.

```
 (with-eval-after-load 'recentf       
    (setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers t))
```

Source: https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/bd7ef98e4c35fd87538dd2a81356cc83f5fd02f3/layers/%2Bcompletion/ivy/packages.el#L146-L150

But I'm not sure of the correct way to trump this setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add your own `with-eval-after-load`.  In your user-config section, insert

```
(with-eval-after-load 'recentf
   (setq ivy-use-virtual-buffers nil))
```